# clustering based particle reconstruction

Tags: unsupervised-learning

I have closely spaced datapoints in 3D space which form V shape with angle between 10 to 20 degree. The datapoints are not well separated. Is there any clustering algorithm that can separate the data into 2 clusters like two parts of V shape?

I have tried distance based algos like hierarchical clustering, K-means and density based dbscan, and pca, gmm too but nothing worked. Basically anything that minimizes distance of any sort do not work.

I am hereby attaching the picture of the data points and what i want the clusters to look like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrVrp.png)

Is there any other method that can work?
Thank you,

Comment: If you just want to separate it out then you can use t-sne plot. Read this : https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/

Comment: i guess t-SNE is for dimentionality reduction, but it already has 3 dim.